# "Tag start is not closed" when commenting inside XML element's start and end tag

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-comments

`<!-- Comment -->` is  the way to add comments in an XML file. Doesn't that actually means, that this part is not "compiled"?

However, when I do something like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/ss3"
    android:icon="@drawable/some_icon"
    android:title="Blabla Title"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    <!-- -->
/>
```

I get an error "Tag start is not closed". Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments are not allowed inside tags. You have to close the tag first with ">" or "/>" and then you can add your comment there.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Pretty stupid if you ask me.. I mean you should be able to add a comment wherever you like. I just don't see the point in that 'rule'.

Comment: If you want to understand why XML is the way it is, you need to understand the history of SGML. I'm no expert, but the basic story is that SGML allowed a vast amount of syntactic variety, far more than anyone needed, and as a result it was difficult and expensive to parse. XML came about from an exercise in reducing SGML to a vastly simpler syntax that removed everything inessential.